# Unable to bind property to correct object

Tags: angularjs, object

I got a list of programs, each program represents an item in the database (Firebase). Each item is recognized by its `key` (as shown in the picture at the bottom). This key is what I'm trying to bind to the `program` object when creating a new program.

However I can't for my life bind the `key` to the `program` object that gets passed to the `addProgram` function.

The finished program object will look something like this:

```
program = {
  label: 'test',
  key: '-jWEOkekoktg534944'
}
```

What I get now for the first item is this, let's assume it's key is `-jWEOkekoktg534944`:

```
program = {
  label: 'test'
}
```

And for the second item:

```
program = {
  label: 'test',
  key: '-jWEOkekoktg534944' // This is the key that the first item should get, but doesn't
}
```

So the third item will get the key of the second item and so on.

Markup for input and button for program creation:

```
<div ng-show="actions.add">
  <input type="text" ng-model="program.label" ng-enter="addProgram(program)">
  <span>
    <button ng-click="addProgram(program)">Add</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here we got the controller, I've got a watch function as well as the `addProgram` function which takes in the `program` object.
The `watch` promise will always resolve before the `addProgram` promise (I checked with the numeric console logs) which is like the last possible reason that I can think of to why this isn't working. I could be horribly wrong however.

```
// Watch for changes in the database
// and update our frontend accordingly
programs.$watch(function(event) {

  // Fetch the programs every time it's updated
  programs = fbRefs.getSyncedArray(path);

  // When the data has finished loading
  // update the programs list or throw an error
  programs.$loaded()
    .then(function(res) {

      console.log(1);
      $scope.programs = res;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      $scope.addError = 'Unable to create a new program';
  });
});

// Add a new program to firebase
$scope.addProgram = function(program) {

  fbCrud.push(path, program)
    .then(function(ref) {

      // Get the key for the item
      // that was just inserted
      var key = ref.key();

      // And assign it to the program
      // object for later use

      console.log(2);
      program.key = key;
  });
};
```

The outcome:

[image: image of outcome]

Here you can see that the items receives the previous item's reference key.
Making the first item have no key and therefore I cannot remove it in the future.

Why isn't this working as it should be?

Comment: a plunkr or jsFiddle would go a long ways to helping us help you

Comment: I agree, there's missing code that is to blame, but we can't see it.